# Why do people use console-based file managers?

Tags: console, filemanager

To keep this question specific and on-topic, let me preface this by stating my intent is not to go into pros and cons of using one type of file manager over another.  However, it is clear a significant group of people use console-based file managers, such as Midnight Commander or Ranger.  I'd like to know their reasons for doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Midnight Commander addict, so let me add a few more points:

- I find dual pane layout to be very efficient for file operations
- Console keyboard managers are more keyboard-friendly, i.e. it is possible to navigate/select files/perform file operations without using mouse. When working in console, switching to mouse is a hindrance
- Console keyboard managers are... well, console-friendly, i.e. it is easy to navigate the filesystem and issue commands in console at the same time. Or even assemble commands from file names you see in `mc` etc.
- Muscular memory. Midnight Commander's commands are largely the same as Norton Commander used to have ages ago.

Answer (score 4):

There may be several reasons:

- They do not depend on X Window, thus can be used even if there are no desktop environment such as a server.
- They are fast and consume less resources (also say above), can be good for old or slow computers.
- They can be powerful and flexible, though you need to learn a bit more than Nautilus.